# EmberJS: How to load assets relative to rootURL or load assets using absolute path

Tags: html, ember.js

this might be a pretty common question but what I found on google does not help me.

I have a emberJs Project with all assets(images, etc) in 
my-ember-project/public/assets/images/
everything works fine when i load the assets from homepage which is the root URL "/" or localhost:4200

for example  in my homepage
I have a component with img tag which looks like this

```
<img src="assets/images/articles/article-1.jpg"/>
```

on another page with url localhost:4200**/articles/** I also load the same image with the same tag
but from what I've seen it tried to load the image from localhost:4200/articles/assets/images/articles/article-1.jpg and not from the correct path localhost:4200/assets/images/articles/article-1.jpg

adding "/" before "assets/images/" works for me if I'm trying to host my project on root folder
but when I need to host my project on subdirectory so my url (www.mydomain.com/ember-project-here/)

how do I load my assets from absolute path or relative to my settings of rootURL
adding {{rootURL}} seems to do nothing to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, `{{rootURL}}` does not work in hbs files (long time ago I used to think it does).

`{{env 'rootURL'}}` should work, where `env` is a helper defined like this:

```
import { get } from '@ember/object';
import { helper } from '@ember/component/helper';
import ENV from 'project-name/config/environment';

export default helper(function([path]) {
  return get(ENV, path);
});
```

Comment: thank you this is perfect! exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a `path` helper:

```
import { helper } from '@ember/component/helper';
import ENV from 'project-name/config/environment';

export default helper(function([path]) {
    return path.replace(/^~\//, ENV.rootURL);
});
```

The  you can do:

```
<img src={{path "~/assets/images/articles/article-1.jpg"}} />
```

This is nice because you can also use variables:

```
<img src={{path this.myPath}} />
```

and `myPath`:

```
get myPath() {
  return `~/assets/images/${this.args.iconName}.jpg`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've done a good research on this front. Yes, `rootURL` is the one you want to add to your project since you are deploying your application to a subfolder.

`rootURL` can be added to any Ember app using the `config/environment.js` file.

```js
// config/environment.js

module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    // other configs...
    rootURL: '/ember-project-here/',
  };
}
```

[The official guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/#toc_specifying-a-root-url) can give you some additional info!

Comment: I did this also, however adding {{rootURL}} to the src does not change the src to ember-project-here/assets/images/articles/article-1.jpg, from the inspect element menu it is assets/images/articles/article-1.jpg as if the {{rootURL}} does nothing.
Do I have to fetch the rootURL data to my model somehow? I'm trying to use rootURL in templates and components by the way. Did I miss something?

I also tried to do this
`<h1>{{rootURL}}</h1>`
to see i my {{rootURL}} outputs anything